# Avoid the same statement in Twig template

Tags: twig, template-engine

I have

```
<div class="{{element.type == 'cover' ? 'cover-full' : 'fixed-width'}}">
    <div class="element 
        {% if element.type == 'text' %}
           element-text
        {% elseif element.type =='image' %}
           element-image
        {% endif %}">

        {% if element.type == 'text' %}
           ...
        {% elseif element.type == 'image' %}
           ...
        {% endif %}
   </div>
```

As you can see I have to make the same `if` condition multiple times. 
How can avoid to repeat every time the condition? I'm pretty new to Twig templating.

Comment: You could use a dynamic include based on the type. This would reduce the number of conditions to one http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#making-an-include-dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will often have abit redundancy. But IMO it is a better practice to repeat HTML blocks instead of twig.

```
{% if element.type == 'text' %}
    <div class="element element-text">
        content
    </div>
{% elseif element.type =='image' %}
     <div class="element element-image">
        content
    </div>
{% else %}
    {% include 'snippet.html' %}
{% endif %}
```

1. You have more valid and more readable HTML
2. If you change a condition you only have to change it one time
3. You could use `{% include 'snippet.html' %}` to reduce redundancy in HTML blocks

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code:

```
{% if element.type in ['text','image'] %}element-{{element.type}}{% endif %}
```

You can use twig macro. On the top of that template add

```
{% macro element_class(type) -%}
    {% if type in ['text','image'] %}element-{{type}}{% endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
{% from _self import element_class %}
```

And later:

```
<div class="{{element.type == 'cover' ? 'cover-full' : 'fixed-width'}}">
    <div class="element {{ element_class(element.type) }}">
```

[You can learn more about macros in Twig documentation.](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)